# C# generated xsd object serialization of datetime

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xml-serialization

I have a generated object from running the xsd.exe which has the following property with backing field:

```
private System.DateTime deliveryDateField;

/// <remarks/>
public System.DateTime DeliveryDate 
{
    get 
    {
        return this.deliveryDateField;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.deliveryDateField = value;
    }
}
```

this is generated from:

```
<xs:element name="DeliveryDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
```

which I am trying to serialize using:

```
var t = new Transaction();
t.DeliveryDate = new DateTime(2011,11,11);
var xs = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());

string outString;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    xs.Serialize(ms, t);
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
       outString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
return outString;
```

whatever value I set this to it is getting lost on the serialization process while other elements are fine. What do I need to do to get this serializing properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably also have a property called DeliveryDateSpecified on your Transaction class? This is because your DeliveryDate is not mandatory. If you set this to true your DeliveryDate will also get serialized.

Comment: Ahhh Thank you I had no idea I needed to do that but makes perfect sense

Comment: The XmlSerializer uses the specified property to determine if a non-nullable property should be serialized.